# Jump Set v. Range of Randome Variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

What is the difference between the range of a random variable X, and its jump set? I know that they are not equivalent sets, e.g. for a continuous RV, the range is $(- \infty , \infty)$, but the jump set is the empty set. Specifically,

- Why, for any random variable X; if range(X) is countable, then X is discrete.
- Similarly, why why binomial, hypergeometric, geometric, and negative binomial random variables must be discrete.
- Why if the jump set for any random variable must be countable.

Answer (score 1):

If $\text{range}(X)$ is countable then $P(X\in D)=1$ with $D$ countable. This is the definition of being discrete.

The examples you cite are all such that $\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb Z}P(X=n)=1$ hence $D=\mathbb Z$ applies.

The third question is the only one with some substance: recall that, by definition, the jump set of $X$ is $J=\{x\mid P(X=x)\ne0\}$. For every integer $n\geqslant1$, consider $J_n=\{x\mid P(X=x)\geqslant1/n\}$, then each set $J_n$ is finite since the size of $J_n$ is at most $n$ (*can you show this?*) and $J=\bigcup\limits_nJ_n$ hence $J$ is at most countable, as union of countably many finite sets.